# iPhone : killing the process from multitasking

Tags: iphone

Why debugger didn't launch to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when I launch the App after killing my app process from multitasking ? "killing app process from multitasking" mean to make double click on "Home" button, after that, at the bottom of iPhone menu with active apps will be shown, and than I delete my app there. thanks...

Comment: Include more details. When were you trying to kill it, what do you mean by "killing (your) app process from multitasking", what does your process do, etc.

Comment: ?? "killing app process from multitasking" mean to make double click on "Home" button, after that, at the bottom of iPhone menu with active apps will be shown, and than I delete my app there.

Comment: That is not obvious from what you wrote. You might want to edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch your app from the iPhone screen (pressing its icon) after you have killed it, the debugger is not attached to it any more, hence it will not launch. You need to trigger the application from XCode again.

Answer (score 0):

If the app's getting killed, regardless of from where, `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` will get called. `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` only gets called when the app launches, not when it quits…hence the names.

Comment: I mean that debugger did not launch didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: when I launch to app second time

Comment: actually `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called if the app is killed by iOS. With iOS 4 introduction of background behaviour `applicationWillTerminate` is only called if device does not support multitasking or iOS Version < 4 or app opted-out of multitasking.